# Splitting excel sheets (Not copy paste data range) into separate workbooks with a certain name

Tags: vba

I have a workbook with multiple sheets that have a name in column AA3 which might match in 2 or more sheets. The macro needs to search these cells and club all sheets with a similar name in AA3 and then make a new workbook out of them using the same name.

Please advise a solution.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I found many codes. They were mostly focused on a data set within a given sheet or the same data set within multiple sheets. However I could not find anything that would search a specific cell in every sheet and club cells with the same name together into a new sheet with a defined syntax. I have also created a table as follows that might help with a code whereby the code can search the sheets listed in the row and put them into the corresponding file name.

Comment: The file name formulae is File Name Formulae:

TEXT(NOW(),"YYYYMM")&" "&B3&" "&C3&".xlsx"

Comment: and the sheets should be arranged thus:

Comment: File Name to be used ShWWt 1 ShWWt 2
201708 W12341170 XZ FU RWviWw Dashboard 2017.xlsx W12341170 PL W12341170 BS
201708 W12341171 XZ FU RWviWw Dashboard 2017.xlsx W12341171 PL W12341171 BS
201708 W12341172 XZ FU RWviWw Dashboard 2017.xlsx W12341172 PL W12341172 BS
201708 W12341173 XZ FU RWviWw Dashboard 2017.xlsx W12341173 PL W12341173 BS
201708 W12341174 XZ FU RWviWw Dashboard 2017.xlsx W12341174 PL W12341174 BS
201708 W12341175 XZ FU RWviWw Dashboard 2017.xlsx W12341175 PL W12341175 BS
201708 W12341176 XZ FU RWviWw Dashboard 2017.xlsx W12341176 PL W12341176 BS

Comment: Why do you not just write your own code then? Coding isnt about "finding", it's about "writing".

Comment: :(.... I'm an accountant and not a programmer. I would love to learn VBA but this is like learning a whole new langauge. I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: The best place to begin is by using the Macro recorder built-in to Excel. Turn it on and do what you want manually, and stop it when you are done. It writes the code for you, and then you can tweak it or paste the results here and ask questions about it.